# How to convert Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleString[] to System.String[]

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, casting

i'm using an Oracle procedure via c# with output parameter, which i'm creating this way:

```
            commandUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                ParameterName = "NAME",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,


            });
            commandUpdate.Parameters["NAME"].Size = Size;
            commandUpdate.Parameters["NAME"].ArrayBindSize = new int[Size];
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            {
                commandUpdate.Parameters["NAME"].ArrayBindSize[i] = 30;
            }
```

and then, after calling `commandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()` i'm trying to cast it to a string array:

```
string[] names = (string[])(commandUpdate.Parameters["NAME"].Value);
```

This brings me to an error `System.InvalidCastException`.

I've tried to use `ToString()` somehow, but seems like it wouldn't work for arrays.

So how can i cast this results to a string array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
OracleString[] namesOra = (OracleString[])(commandUpdate.Parameters["NAME"].Value);
names = namesOra.Select(os => os.IsNull ? null : os.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an OracleString variable that will be a variable holding one element at a time from an array. Let's say this variable will be called `oraStringVar`.

Assign a value to it by:

```
oraStringVar = someListVar[index].Value;
```

Then you may extract what you need by executing:

```
string container = oraStringVar.Value
```

Note doubled use of `Value`. The same works for extracting clob to a string.

Comment: it's an object type by default, so i'm not able to use index there

Comment: how was ["is_actuial"] defined? I don't see it in your question

Comment: sorry, ofc there is a "NAME" there, copied from another line of code.